# Python - ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, django, api, oauth, vimeo

Please check this question [Python oauth2 - making request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070885/python-oauth2-making-request) I am working with vimeo integration in my web application.

Initially I got an **oauth_signature** and I had no problems(no errors), I tried those things once again from the first and Now I'm getting **ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack** while making this request

```
>>> r = request.get(url, headers=headers)
```

You can check out my code here https://gist.github.com/2949182

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 51, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 39, in request
return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 159, in request
headers[k] = header_expand(v)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/requests/utils.py", line 152, in header_expand
for i, (value, params) in enumerate(headers):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
>>> headers
{'Authorization': u'oauth_body_hash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,oauth_nonce=3454768,oauth_timestamp=1340035585,oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,oauth_callback=http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/vimeo'}
```

Comment: Try `r = requests.get(url, params=headers)` - `get()` don't accept headers

Comment: @astynax No. not working and that is not the right format for vimeo oauth request.

Comment: What is assigned to `headers`?

Comment: post() accepts headers: `requests.post(url, headers=headers)`

Comment: Please print headers before "r = request.get(url, headers=headers)"

Comment: Try it: headers = {'Authorization': 'oauth_body_hash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}

Comment: @Goin Now I'm getting response[401].

Comment: @Goin How these things worked before but not now?

Answer (score 7):

to be able to unpack a dictionary you would have to use the .items(), so the code would be like this:

```
for i, (value, params) in enumerate(headers.items()):
```

now since that is not your code and you can't change it, what the error is telling you is that the headers should not be a dictionary but a tuple (or a list), if you pass the header like this:

```
headers = [("Authorization", "Values")]
```

it should work.

EDIT: This doesn't works. Now the dictionary version {"Authorization": "Values"} works for me, maybe updating requests will help.

Comment: checking the code from the library. It works for me using the dictionary version. My requests library version is 0.10.8