# Python oauth2 - getting access token

Tags: python, django, api, oauth, vimeo

I want to integrate authenticated vimeo user's videos in my web application. I have this code https://gist.github.com/2944212

I made authorize call and now I got **oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_verifier**. I added all these things to the parameter and made request to the below url, but now I'm getting this error

```
>>> url = 'http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token'
>>> req = oauth.Request(method='GET', url=url, parameters=params)
>>> req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2/__init__.py", line 502, in sign_request
self['oauth_signature'] = signature_method.sign(self, consumer, token)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2/__init__.py", line 838, in sign
key, raw = self.signing_base(request, consumer, token)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2/__init__.py", line 832, in signing_base
key += escape(token.secret)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'secret'
```

Using that how can I fetch **access_token** and make this method to work https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getUploaded

I'm new to oauth and I need your help.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Now I solved that error. The only thing I need is to get the access token and a script to make the request for this method https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getUploaded

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you now have the access token?

To make requests to the API endpoint follow the same procedure but use the access token (as the oauth_token parameter) and in the req.sign method. Direct your request towards the API URL aswell, of course :)

And you don't need the oauth_verifier once you have the access token.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151595/python-oauth-for-youtube